# Update database schema while preserving data (and relationships)

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade

I have a simple database schema containing 5 tables and a few foreign key relationships. Now I want to update the schema without losing the relationships.

SQLite does not support the operation I want to perform. I want to mark a column AUTOINCREMENT. So I searched and found that I need to recreate the tables.

In all the relationships, foreign key is the auto-generated row ID. This will change when I re-insert the data (right?). And the best case scenario would be having mismatched relationships. The worst case (I think) would be having foreign keys that correspond to nothing. How do I avoid this?

One way that I can think of doing this is through dumping all data into a special model designed for this very exercise. This special model will encapsulate all the relationships. Then I can start creating new tables in order of ascending dependence, from least to most. Table that has no foreign keys (but other tables use its ID) goes in first. And on inserting rows, I update the model instance.

Is there a better way of doing this? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Values in an autoincrementing column can be set to an explicit value:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyAutoincID, Name) VALUES(42, 'hello')
```

Just copy the ID together with the other column values.

Furthermore, as long as you do not enable foreign key checking with [PRAGMA foreign_keys](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) or [setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled%28boolean%29), your DB is allowed to have inconsistent data temporarily.

Comment: It is funny how the documentation starts making sense once you have sort of implemented the product. I went back to `autoincrement` documentation and it seems that iff the old database was in a consistent state, `INSERT INTO MyTable(MyAutoincID, Name) VALUES(42, 'hello')` will be fine. But as my table ids do not currently autoincrement, row ids are not in an increasing order. Will this not be a problem since the new table has the autoincrement contraint?

Comment: AUTOINCREMENT is not a constraint, it is just a mechanism to automatically assign an ID value if you insert a NULL.

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant this: I insert 4 entries. Generated ids will be 1,2,3,4. then I delete the entry with id=2. I insert another item: generated id will be 2 since there is no autoincrement right now. Now, row ids in order are: 1,3,4,2. When I try to transfer this to a new table with autoincrement, won't the last item (id=2) be assigned id=5 since 2 cannot be assigned? This will affect the foreign-key relationship.

Comment: There is no such problem. Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).